# toggle a dotted border when using jquery .toggleClass()

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to toggle a dotted border around a selected p tag when it is clicked on.

I formatted it using css script and then added a toggleClass() in jQuery, but when I ran my program, it didn't work. The dotted border doesn't appear.

Does anyone know how to make toggleClass() jQuery work? Thank you, in advance.

I will share my code below: https://codepen.io/monkeycrane2010/pen/poEXENr

**HTML**

```
<h1 style="text-align: center;">Baseline</h1>
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
 
  <p>Text box to drag</p>
</div>

<button id="sheepbtn">+New </button>

<div id="one">Library Box</div>

<p>animal rocks!</p>
```

**CSS**

```
#draggable {
     width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; 
};

.selected {
  border: 10px dotted orange;
};
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function () {
  $("#draggable").draggable();
  $("#draggable").resizable();

  $("#sheepbtn").on("click", function () {
    $("#one").append($("<p>tester</p>").draggable()); // CREATE NEW

    $("p").each(function (index) {
      // EACH
      $(this).attr("id", index);
      console.log(index + ": " + $(this).text());
    });

    $("p").on("click", function (event) {
      // CLASS
      $("h1").html(this.id);
      $(this).toggleClass("selected");
    });
  });
  
});
```

Comment: see my codepen https://codepen.io/monkeycrane2010/pen/poEXENr

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your toggle seems to work, but it's only going to work after you hit "New+" button. If you want it to work all the time, move that bit of code out of the creation of the new item.

Comment: thanks @Twisty for the warm welcome to this community an also your suggestion! Ended up that I had a newbie syntax error in my css file (I had accidentally added semicolon at end of each property, once I took that out.. it worked!).  I also found another way using mousemove and mouseleave to give the selected effect. --- I just updated my codepen

Comment: You're welcome @MonkeyCrane I posted an answer that includes the cleaned up CSS and some suggestions. If it helps, give it a n upvote. If it does answer your question, click the check mark or if it doesn't, you can answer your own question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I answered my own question - see my comment above. I made a css syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a function like so:

```
function makeNewDrag(str, trg) {
  str = str != undefined ? str : "";
  trg = trg != undefined ? $(trg) : $("body");
  var n = $("<div>", {
    class: "draggable ui-widget-content"
  }).appendTo(trg);
  $("<p>").html(str).appendTo(n);
  n.draggable().resizable()
  return n;
}
```

This way, you can use it like `makeNewDrag("Tester", $("#one"))`.

Here is a more full example. This applies a `click` callback to all `p` elements that are direct children to `.draggable` elements.

```js
$(function() {
  function makeNewDrag(str, trg) {
    str = str != undefined ? str : "";
    trg = trg != undefined ? $(trg) : $("body");
    var n = $("<div>", {
      class: "draggable ui-widget-content"
    }).appendTo(trg);
    $("<p>").html(str).appendTo(n);
    n.draggable().resizable()
    return n;
  }
  $(".draggable").draggable().resizable();

  $("#sheepbtn").on("click", function() {
    makeNewDrag("Tester", $("#one"));
  });

  $("body").on("click", ".draggable > p", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
  });
});
```

```css
.draggable {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.selected {
  border: 10px dotted orange;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<h1 style="text-align: center;">Baseline</h1>
<div class="draggable ui-widget-content">
  <p>Text box to drag</p>
</div>

<button id="sheepbtn">+New</button>

<div id="one" class="draggable ui-widget-content">Library Box</div>

<p>animal rocks!</p>
```

See More:

- https://api.jquery.com/on/

> When a `selector` is provided, the event handler is referred to as *delegated*. The handler is not called when the event occurs directly on the bound element, but only for descendants (inner elements) that match the selector. jQuery bubbles the event from the event target up to the element where the handler is attached (i.e., innermost to outermost element) and runs the handler for any elements along that path matching the selector.

Comment: thanks. I did not end up using this solution, but since I am new to jQuery - this is so helpful to see you can still create function and call it in jQuery.

Comment: @MonkeyCrane you can always upvote an answer that you found helpful. You should also check the check mark for the answer you posted.